# How do you parse date in the format:

Tags: date, parsing, go

It's not clear to me from the documentation how I would parse a date in this somewhat strange format. It seems like it might not be possible.

```
2016-07-08T08:34:24+00:00
```

The following does not work ([go play link](https://play.golang.org/p/y32_lewh-F))

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    date := "2016-07-08T08:34:24+00:00"
    d, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05+07:00", date)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println(d)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Obviously a regexp could first check for this format and transform the `+` to a `-`, but that implies the standard library *cant* parse this date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go's reference layout uses -7 hours as the timezone offset, but you used +7 hours:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    date := "2016-07-08T08:34:24+00:00"
    d, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05-07:00", date)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println(d)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/FNzx57R2jy